# Creating a unique index between two navigation properties using Entity Framework Code-First v6.0

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I'm working on an Entity Framework 6 Code First project and I need to create a *Unique Index* that include two navigation properties.

For some unknown reason when I do the migration *add-migration Foo* the generated code create two separated indexes (one for each property).

Here's the code snippet of the generated code

```
.Index(t => t.a)
.Index(t => t.b)
```

Now if I do the same with two non-navigation properties the generated code is the expected

Here's the code snippet with the properties and the data annotations

```
[Index("IX_1", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int a { get; set; }

[Index("IX_1", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int b { get; set; }
```

and here's the code snippet of the generated code (the expected one)

```
.Index(t => new { t.a, t.b }, unique: true, name: "IX_1")
```

I'm applying the same annotations with the non-navigation properties and the navigation properties.

Why it doesn't generate the correct code with navigation properties?

Can somebody tell me if there's a way to make it works with the navigation properties?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. So Navigation properties represent relationship, Non-Navigation properties represents Columns. I don't think apply Index to a Navigation Property (that's just a relationship) should work. Please correct if I am wrong somewhere?

Comment: I just tried using two non-navigation properties to check the Migration's result, they're useless. What I need is to create the Unique Index between the two navigation properties

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?